# How to use various realm databases?

Tags: android, database, realm

i need to use 4 realm databases in order to save 4 different objects in each one, im new in programming and realm and im learning but i found this in realm docs:

`RealmConfiguration myConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .name("myrealm.realm")
  .schemaVersion(2)
  .modules(new MyCustomSchema())
  .build();`

`RealmConfiguration otherConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .name("otherrealm.realm")
  .schemaVersion(5)
  .modules(new MyOtherSchema())
  .build();`

`Realm myRealm = Realm.getInstance(myConfig);
Realm otherRealm = Realm.getInstance(otherConfig);`

I think that this code should go in the MyApplicacion class, but i cant set a `DefaultInstance` so in my MainActivity i cant get the default instance and use it as always,i need to get the instance with the conf i want.
Its my first time in stackoverflow so sorry for my mistakes and my bad english. Thanks you all.

Comment: Are you sure about needing different databases? you probably just need one Database and different tables for the Objects.

Comment: `need to get the instance with the conf i want.` yes, that is how

Comment: maybe this is the solution but i dont know ho to do it @ariochdivij666

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but i need to see it in code and knowing the place to use it